# Getting 'image' error when no image is selected

Tags: django, python-3.x

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
     Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
     Image: <input type="File" name="image"><br>
     <input type="submit">
<form>
```

```py
# views.py
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        obj = ImageF()
        obj.title = request.POST.get('title']
        obj.pic = request.FILES['image']
        obj.save()
    except Exception as e:
        print('error', e)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I'm trying to upload an image into my database.

Whenever I don't select the image it throws an error in `views.py` for 'image', even though in `models.py` 'null' and 'blank' is `TRUE`.

Comment: change `request.FILES['image']` for  `request.FILES.get('image', None)`

Comment: You should show your model code. Also, by any chance it's possible that you're forgot to migrate after a alowing image filed to be null?

Comment: May I kindly suggest you use [a django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) ?

Comment: @Charnel definitely that's not the case, all changes things are updated

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski, I tried 'obj.pic = request.FILES.get('image',None)" then I got an error i.ie "error 'method' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: btw you have different brackets here `request.POST.get('title']`

Comment: @Charnel yeah I changed it in the actual code

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've done it using django forms and got no issues, it's just that I want to try it with raw html form

Comment: My bad.....obj.pic = request.FILES.get('image',None) <- working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following line

> `obj.pic = request.FILES['image']`

to

> `obj.pic = request.FILES.get('image',None)`

It will store `None` when it has no any images uploaded by user.

[jacek B Budzynski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5638542/jacek-b-budzynski) Already mentioned.